# Docker volume, change file permissions/owner

Tags: permissions, docker, docker-compose

I'm running ruby on rails in a docker container. If I generate something like `docker-compose run rails rails g controller posts index show`, the file owner is root. After that I must always run `chown -R . $USER` and this is annoying.

Does any one know how I can fix this, so that the owner from each generated file is the host user?

Answer (score 0):

You can run with `docker-compose run --user $USER`, but that user must already exist in the container, so you'd have to create it in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Note that user names are not important - _user ids_ are. So find the uid of your user on the host and create a user with a matching uid in the Dockerfile.