# Docker VOLUME for different users

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I'm using docker and docker-compose for building my app. There are two developers now for the project hosted on github.

Our project structure is:

- sup

  - dockerfiles

    - dev

      - build

        - .profile
        - Dockerfile
      - docker-compose.yml

Now we have `./dockerfiles/dev/docker-compose.yml` like this:

```
app:
    container_name: sup-dev
    build: ./build
```

and `./dockerfiles/dev/build/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM sup:dev

# docker-compose tries to find .profile relative to build dir:
# ./dockerfiles/dev/build
COPY .profile /var/www/
```

We run container like so:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Everything works fine, but due to different OS we have our code in different places: `/home/aliance/www/project` for me and `/home/user/other/path/project` for the second developer. So I can not just add volume instruction into `Dockerfile`.

Now we solve this problem in this wrong way:
- I am using lsyncd with my personal config to transfer files into the container
- While the second one uses `volume` instruction into `Dockerfile` but not commited it.

May be you know how can I write an unified `Dockerfile` for `docker-compose` to volume out code into app container from different paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file paths on the host shouldn't matter. Why do you need absolute paths?

You can use paths that are relative to the `docker-compose.yml` so they should be the same for both developers.

The `VOLUME` instructions in the Dockerfile are always relative to the build context, so if you want, you can use something like this:

```
app:
    container_name: sup-dev
    build: ..
    dockerfile: build/Dockerfile
```

That way the build context for the `Dockerfile` will be the project root.

Comment: Hello @dnephin, thanx for your answer. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but will parent paths works? As I remember in security reasons they are disabled.

Comment: I’ve confused build path and `ADD` instruction into `Dockerfile`. Your solution works for me. What changes I have done: 1) in `docker-compose.yml` I've changed `build` to `../..` and set `dockerfile` to `./dockerfiles/dev/build` and 2) changed path to `.profile` file into my `Dockerfile`, now it became relative to build context — `COPY ./dockerfiles/dev/build/.profile /var/www/` (see my edited question above, I’ve clarified project structure, It has 2 level nesting). Everything looks good now, yeap?

Comment: Hmm, but does not work with volume. As a read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311613/docker-mounting-volumes-on-host), the `Dockerfile` `VOLUME` and `docker-compose.yml` `volumes` (same as `docker run -v`) is not the same. I want to use the second one, so I tried to add this `../..:/var/www/project` in my `docker-compose.yml` (notice, that path is relative to yml, not build context), all files from app root (build context) are copied to container root path `/var/www/project` but they changed its owner:group at my local host to `www-data`. Is it okay? Or what should I do?

Comment: Yes, there are two types of volumes, container volumes (`VOLUME` in a `Dockerfile`) and host volumes (mounting a host path into a container). It sounds like you want a host volume.  If they are changing ownership, there must be something that runs in the container which changes their ownership.  Ownership of files is preserved.  I should be ok, you can just add your user to the www-group and give them `chmod g+w` permision.

Comment: Yeap, host volume suits me the best. No, there are noone who changes files permissions. I found your answer to the [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33508123/3456488) so this is not only my _local_ problem? I've already thought about adding my local user to `www-data` group, but don't sure this is ok. Ok, I'll try and post a feedback. Thanx for your help!

Comment: Tried to add my local user to `www-data` group - everything works fine! Used command: `sudo usermod -aG www-data <username>` (needs shell restart). Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should keep your Dockerfile at the root of your project. Then you could add an instruction in the Dockerfile:

```
COPY ./ /usr/src/app/
```

or (not recommended in prod)

```
VOLUME /usr/src/app
```

+ (option while running the container as I don't know docker-compose)

```
-v /path/to/your/code:/usr/src/app
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer. «you should keep your Dockerfile at the root of your project» — That doesn’t suits me. «not recommended in prod» — this is need for dev platform, ’cause only dev platform can be run into different environment. Can you explain a little bit more about your solution with «volume path», can’t understand how it can helps me.